# Full Page Browser Ambient Video problems

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I've used the simple CSS method of implementing an ambient background video into my website. And I thought everything was okay, but each browser seems to have a unique problem....except IE, which works perfectly for some reason, I know that's a first.

**Chrome:** Loads video on top of content, then on reload or window resize it tucks the video behind my content like it should have to begin with.

**Firefox:** Doesn't load the video at all. Just the preload image.

**Safari:** Loads the preload image, then the video in the background, but the video is invisible until I resize the page or reload it.

The website is at [www.bugejastudio.com](http://www.bugejastudio.com)

Is there anything that I'm clearly doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your site worked as you expected for me in Chrome and Firefox. Perhaps you are running older versions of these browsers? Though the video did not work on my phone (presumably because of the autoplay restrictions that mobile devices tend to have).

Comment: It doesn't play video on mobile devices, correct. I think yes, due to the autoplay restrictions, but mobile doesn't bother me too much. All browsers are up to date.

Comment: Though I haven't tested it, instead of autoplay, you might be able to do the following jQuery call to have the video play on mobile devices `$('#bgvid').get(0).play()`. Sorry, I cannot replicate your issue. I'm not sure what might cause it.

Comment: I fixed some of the problems. I guess the only one I really want prioritized is Chrome loading the video on top rather than underneath where it belongs. I'm wondering if there is some sort of refresh you can do on the objects that get hidden by the video, to refresh their z-index or redraw them to see if they show up on top?